# How do solve left gap semantically in Media Queries menu

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a css issue with a media queries menu, I want the dropdown menu to be 100% width but there is a css issue on the left hand side of the menu showing a gap.

Any help would be great!!

please see fiddle here 
http://jsfiddle.net/kavbE/

```
body {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    background: #fff;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #4083a9;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #205f82;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.98);
    z-index: 9997;
}
#header-inner {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 12px;
    max-width: 970px;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 0 0;
}
#logo a {
    display: block;
    width: 82px;
    height: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 50%;
    background-image: url(../img/assets/chartego-logo.png);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}
#logo img {
    height: 0;
}
#logo a:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
#nav {
    margin: 0 0px 0 20px;
    color: #777;
}
#nav>li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1;
}
#nav>li>a {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}
#nav>li#user-profile {
    float: right;
}
#nav>li img {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top:13px;
}
#nav li ul.tabs {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    background: #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    z-index: 999;
}
#nav li ul.tabs li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 2;
    color: #999;
    background: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#nav li ul.tabs li a:hover {
    color: #ddd;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#nav li:hover>a, #nav li>a:hover {
    color: #ddd;
}
#nav li#user-profile ul.tabs li:first-child a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#toggle-nav {
    display: none;
}
#nav li#user-profile span.profile-name {
    display: none;
}
/* =============================================================================
  NAVIGATION MEDIA MAX 800PX
   ========================================================================== */
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #header {
        position: fixed;
        height: 40px;
    }
    #toggle-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0px;
        display: block;
        width: 48px;
        height: 40px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 15px 50%;
        background-image: url(../img/assets/icon-hamburger.png);
        opacity: .5;
    }
    #logo a {
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }
    #logo {
        float: none;
        padding-right: 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #nav {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #nav li {
        position: relative;
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 12px;
        background: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.98);
    }
    #nav li ul.tabs {
        display: block;
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    #nav li ul.tabs li a {
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    #nav li#user-profile {
        float: none;
    }
    #nav li#user-profile img {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    }
    #nav li#user-profile span.profile-name {
        display: inline;
    }
    #nav li a:hover {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    #nav li a:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }
    #nav li ul.tabs li a:hover {
        color: #999;
        background: none;
    }
    #nav li#user-profile ul.tabs li:first-child {
        display: none;
    }
    #header-inner {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some browser-default padding on your #nav list.

Add `padding: 0;` to `#nav` and it should fix it.